# WP_Query with child element

Tags: wp-query, query, post-meta

I have my calendar events, I want to sort them by creation date with the query, but here's the issue:

I have a meta key which has child values:
First one is `$data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_event_data',true);`
and then I get `$date = $data['begin'];`

I need to make the query sort based on the `$date = $data['begin']` but how do I do it before the loop?
I can't change the code, how am I able to get it? Everything and anyhow how I try to fix it, it orders the events by the automatically given id.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_event_data',true);
```

to

```
$data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_event_data',false);
```

As stated in the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/),

> Return: (mixed) Will be an array if $single is false. Will be value of meta data field if $single is true.

But somehow I'd just guess that `_event_data` doesn't hold much more than the actual (event-) ID. You'd probably have to make a second `get_metadata` function to retrieve all info for the event based on its ID. (see: [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/))

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you cannot do an `ORDER BY` in a mysql query with a serialized array, as in your case.

A solution way will be to store the dates as separate meta entries, so you can query by their values, something like this:

```
    $sorted_calendar_events = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => '...',
        'meta_key' => '_event_begin',
        'orderby' => array( 'meta_value', 'date' ),
        'order' => 'DESC'
    ));
```

Given the fact that `_event_begin` is stored in a `Y-m-d` format or something similar.

If `_event_begin` is stored as unix time, and orderby `meta_value_num` should be used.